# Evaluate JavaScript source block in org-mode

Tags: org-babel, javascript

If I attempt to evaluate a JavaScript source block then I have to `return` a value to get a result.  For example:

```
#+begin_src js
  return 1 + 2;
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 3
```

That's a bit unusual.  I guess that the code block is treated as the body of a function.  Should I have to use `return` to get the result of this expression?

Comment: https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html suggests you have to do the same in python and some other languages. I'm not sure how to find out which languages require the `return` statement and which do not.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I followed that and this all makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 4):

For future passengers, `:results value` (the default option) requires an explicit `return` statement to display its value. On the other hand, `:results output` displays everything from the standard output.

##### Examples

In both cases, `1+2` is not enough.

```
#+begin_src js :results value
return 1 + 2;
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 3
```

```
#+begin_src js :results output
console.log(1 + 2);
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 3
```

##### [Documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html)

> ‘value’
>
> **Default** for most Babel libraries. **Functional mode**. Org gets the value by wrapping the code in a function definition in the language of the source block. That is why when using ‘:results value’, code should execute like a function and return a value. For languages like Python, **an explicit return statement is mandatory** when using ‘:results value’. **Result is the value returned** by the last statement in the code block.
>
> ...

> ‘output’
>
> **Scripting mode**. Org passes the code to an external process running the interpreter. Org **returns the contents of the standard output stream as text results**.
>
> ...